# Apache Commons FileUpload getString() method - Java

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, apache-commons

My FileUpload Servlet code:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    NewsItems ni = new NewsItems();
    if (isMultipart) {
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        try {
            List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
            String [] myValues = new String[6];
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();

                int i = 0;
                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    myValues[i] = item.getString();
                    System.out.println("my vals: "+myValues[i]); //PRINTS THE VALUES
                }
                i++;
            }
            String newsContent = myValues[2]; //PRINTS NULL
            System.out.println(newsContent);

        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm trying to assign `getString()` values to a `String` Array. In above the code , `System.out.println` which is inside the `While` Loop prints the values but the `System.out.println` outside prints `NULL`. Any reasons for this and can someone please provide me a solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: How often does the loop iterate? Print the whole array. Maybe the third field is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer. I have done a silly mistake by initializing the `i` inside the while loop.

```
int i = 0;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
        myValues[i] = item.getString();
        System.out.println("my vals: "+myValues[i]); //PRINTS THE VALUES
    }
    i++;
}
```